# Почему нет ConcurrentList<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

В .NET есть такая структура как потокобезопасный словарь ConcurrentDictionary. А вот потокобезопасного списка почему-то нет? Может кто-то знает почему? Заранее спасибо

Comment: [в двух словах, потому что List<T> с локами оказывается быстрее](https://books.google.ru/books?id=NiZ0UWnAn44C&pg=PT1171&lpg=PT1171&dq=ConcurrentList%3CT%3E&source=bl&ots=zoeJYzSonQ&sig=zI-0kw1Rn9uwOuY0-0yxC1hnQYI&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi18eq--fnKAhXEmQ4KHVEvAMAQ6AEIVzAH#v=onepage&q=ConcurrentList%3CT%3E&f=false)

Comment: Думаю, потому что индекс элемента, в отличие от ключа, не является безопасным. Если вы добавляете элемент с ключом в Dictionary, и потом удаляете элемент по другому ключу, вы сможете получить доступ по старому ключу. А вот удаление элемента из списка инвалидирует все индексы.

Comment: [и еще ответ на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6601832/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy а не потрудитесь ли запилить переводы двух источников в виде ответа? Плюс гарантирую :).

Comment: @andreycha, если только вечером :-) по первой ссылке, кстати, цитата из книжки [C# 5.0 Unleashed 1st Edition
by Bart De Smet (Author)](http://www.amazon.com/5-0-Unleashed-Bart-De-Smet/dp/0672336901)

Comment: @Grundy, а вот Страуструп и Ко утверждают, что они сделали lock-free vector быстрее, чем lock-based версия. Поэтому то, что написано в этой книге весьма сомнительно.

Comment: @ixSci, ничего не могу сказать про плюсы :-)

Comment: @ixSci Grundy имхо не совсем верно перевел. Там написано, что сделать эффективную реализацию `ConcurrentList` непросто, и что такая реализация будет не сильно быстрее обычного листа с локами (в отличие от стэка и очереди), поэтому решили не запариваться.

Comment: @andreycha, вполне возможно, спасибо за поправку :-)

Comment: @Grundy, std::vector и List близнецы братья, по своей сути.

Comment: @ixSci, я думаю тут стоит смотреть именно внутреннюю реализацию, не удивлюсь если она довольно сильно будет отличаться

Comment: @andreycha, я уверен, что причина именно в этом: «решили не запариваться». Но вот как я уже сказал(ссылка у меня в ответе есть), Страуструп утверждает, что они получили 10-и кратное ускорение, по сравнению с lock-based версией.

Comment: @ixSci: Возможно, это из-за меньшей нагрузки на аллокатор. Стандартный аллокатор в C++ медленный, так что 10-кратное увеличение может быть лишь из-за этого. Интересно сравнить по скорости `List<int>` с lock'ом и ту самую имплементацию, которая в 10 раз быстрее :-D

Comment: Если вам дали исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Почему бы не поставить галочку наиболее полезному ответу?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Почему нет ConcurrentList<T>?
>   Ответ в том, что все `Concurrent*` коллекции в пространстве имен [*System.Collections.Concurrent*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) имеют чрезвычайно эффективные и масштабируемые реализации. То есть, внутри они используют такие облегченные примитивы синхронизации, как [*SpinLock*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.spinlock(v=vs.110).aspx) и [*SpinWait*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.spinwait(v=vs.110).aspx). Фактически, реализации [*ConcurrentQueue<T>*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) и [*ConcurrentStack<T>*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd267331(v=vs.110).aspx) не используют вообще никаких локов.
>   Это привело к тому, что написание такого же эффективного списка стало нелегкой задачей.
>   Как результат, отсутствует тип *ConcurrentList<T>*, потому что его реализация не будет ощутимо лучше *List<T>* с классическим локом (который будет довольно тяжелым)

[C# 5.0 Unleashed

Bart De Smet](https://books.google.ru/books?id=NiZ0UWnAn44C&pg=PT1171&lpg=PT1171&dq=ConcurrentList%3CT%3E&source=bl&ots=zoeJYzSonQ&sig=zI-0kw1Rn9uwOuY0-0yxC1hnQYI&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi18eq--fnKAhXEmQ4KHVEvAMAQ6AEIVzAH#v=onepage&q=ConcurrentList%3CT%3E&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

В интерфейсе `IList<T>` есть методы для работы с элементами по их индексу. Однако в многопоточной среде элементы в любой момент могут быть удалены или сдвинуты со своего места, а значит доступ по индексу теряет смысл. Поэтому потокобезопасного списка `ConcurrentList<T>` нет, но есть потокобезопасная коллекция `BlockingCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю точной причины, остаётся только гадать. На мой взгляд, такой структуры нет из-за того, что `List` в C# содержит элементы одним куском(contiguous memory), а реализовать такую структуру в терминах lock-free довольно сложно, видимо. Все примеры lock-free или wait-free структур, что я видел были основаны на узлах, которые ссылались друг на друга. Видимо, это довольно сложно сделать со структурой, у которой нет узлов, поэтому решили, что «овчинка выделки не стоит».

Вот нашёл описание [lock-free vector](http://www.stroustrup.com/lock-free-vector.pdf) для С++, что подойдёт для List из C#, в целом.

Answer (score -1):

Это сделано в угоду производительности. Если есть именно необходимость потокобезопасного списка используйте CopyOnWriteArrayList

A thread-safe variant of {@link java.util.ArrayList} in which all mutative
operations ({@code add}, {@code set}, and so on) are implemented by
making a fresh copy of the underlying array.

Comment: сдесь вообще речь про .NET и c# :-)