# Потокобезопасные списки C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, коллекции

У меня вопрос, есть ли какие нибудь потокобезопасные списки?
Я понимаю что можно использовать `lock`, но интересует способ без использования блокировки коллекции.

Просто в теории допустим, что есть около 20 потоков которые работают с 1 коллекцией и как можно добавлять и изымать оттуда "информацию".

Comment: [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=net-5.0)

Comment: [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: https://youtu.be/fQhz2iHmwV8?t=1449

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ахаха :) оставлю как есть

Comment: [Thread-Safe Collections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/)

Comment: [Immutable Collections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/net-framework-immutable-collections)

Comment: Вот теперь хорошо!

Comment: [Почему нет ConcurrentList<T>?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/493694/373567)

Comment: Спасибо большое) А почему тогда не используют каррентлист на постоянке? Т.е я когда обычно смотрю какие то мануалы, то часто вижу что используют просто `List`

Comment: @GRAMOTEYTV `каррентлист` - КонкуррентЛист? Потому что его не существует в .NET? Потому что каждый пилит себе решение как умеет?)

Comment: На постоянке конкуррентные коллекции не используют потому, что они работают медленнее. Там хоть и эффективная реализация внутри, но всё равно накладные расходы есть и при вставке, и при удалении, и даже просто при получении элементов.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Так как комментариев накидали много, а прямого дубликата данного вопроса я не нашел, оформлю ответом.

#### Потокобезопасные коллекции

Пространство имён `System.Collections.Concurrent` ([документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=net-5.0)) содержит все стандартные потокобезопасные коллекции. Их поведение и методы отличаются от обычных аналогов, поэтому стоит изучить, как с ними правильно работать. Половина потокобезопасных коллекций строится на [интерфейсе](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.iproducerconsumercollection-1?view=net-5.0) `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`, он то и добавляет что-то общее между этими коллекциями. Остальные имеют более специфическое назначение.

Почитать про потокобезопасные коллекции можно [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/). Можно посмотреть даже [видео](https://youtu.be/fQhz2iHmwV8?t=1449).

#### ConcurrentList<T>

Так же стоит отметить, что в .NET отсутствует коллекция `ConcurrentList<T>`, есть [подробный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/493694/373567) на этот вопрос.

Вот пример реализации самого простого потокобезопасного списка на базе `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, который я когда-то написал для другого ответа. Можно считать это болванкой для своего собственного решения.

**ConcurrentList.cs**

```cs
public class ConcurrentList<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _list;
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock;

    public int Count 
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                _lock.EnterReadLock();
                return _list.Count;
            }
            finally
            {
                _lock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public ConcurrentList() : this(null) { }

    public ConcurrentList(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        _list = items is null ? new List<T>() : new List<T>(items);
        _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        try
        {
            _lock.EnterWriteLock();
            _list.Add(item);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        try
        {
            _lock.EnterWriteLock();
            _list.Clear();
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        try
        {
            _lock.EnterReadLock();
            return _list.Contains(item);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        try
        {
            _lock.EnterReadLock();
            _list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        try
        {
            _lock.EnterWriteLock();
            return _list.Remove(item);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> Enumerate()
    {
        try
        {
            _lock.EnterReadLock();
            foreach (T item in _list)
                yield return item;
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        => Enumerate().GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => Enumerate().GetEnumerator();
}
```

#### Неизменяемые коллекции

Так же существуют [неизменяемые коллекции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-5.0) `System.Collections.Immutable`. Они тоже являются потокобезопасными, так как данные в них нельзя изменить, а следовательно к ним можно получать безопасный доступ из нескольких потоков. Подробнее почитать можно [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/net-framework-immutable-collections).

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ

Comment: Я рад наконец слышать от вас `а прямого дубликата данного вопроса я не нашел`. Лайк от меня.

Comment: Идея выдавать энумерацию под локом может приводить к deadlock-ам. Об этом пишет Эрик тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe, текст "Except... there could be something super-complicated in that delegate. What if whatever is in the delegate happens to cause an event that triggers code to run on another thread, which in turn causes some queue operation to run, which in turn blocks in such a manner that we've produced a deadlock?" Вот иллюстрация: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GfYJMs

Comment: Потокобезопасная коллекция вообще не может иметь такой же интерфейс, как обычная, т. к. требования к энумерации очень разные. Даёт ли энумерация snapshot? Реагирует ли она динамически на изменение коллекции во время энумерации? Какой смысл свойства Count? Как организовать доступ по индексу? Всё это сложные вопросы.

Comment: @VladD у меня вообще почти Producer/Consumer коллекция, немного урезана. Никто не реализует здесь `IList<T>`, и не пытается. Я тоже считаю, что от свойства `Count` толку никакого, но оно есть у всех коллекций из `System.Collections.Concurrent` и вроде никто не жалуется. Выше в примере нет никакой отсебятины, я просто реализовал 2 интерфейса, ни больше не меньше. Или я не понял ваш комментарий.

Comment: @VladD `Идея выдавать энумерацию под локом может приводить к deadlock-ам.` я это осознавал, когда писал этот код. Поэтому энумератор и надо диспозить своевременно. Считаю, что это ответственность кода, использующего данную коллекцию.

Comment: @aepot: Ну вот есть пример на dotnetfiddle — какая часть кода неправа? `OnLoaded` закрывает энумерацию так быстро, как только может. Аналогичный код с [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netcore-3.1) работает нормально (я только поменял `Remove` на `Add`).