# Использование черного списка C# + Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, proxy

В общем, у меня есть программа которая парсит некие данные с разных интернет магазинов. Бывает такое, что при частых запросах моя прокся улетает в бан на некоторое время.
И у меня появилась идея сделать черный список для прокси, улетевших в бан с таймером, по истечению которого, прокся обратно возвращалась в коллекцию.
Я написал такой код, но не уверен что он рабочий и вообще правильный, есть ли еще какие то способы для создания решения подобный задач?

```
public class Proxy : INetwork
{
    private readonly Random rand;
    private readonly List<string> data;
    private readonly List<string> black;

    public Proxy()
    {
        rand = new Random();

        data = new List<string>();
        black = new List<string>();

        lockObject = new object();
    }

    private readonly object lockObject;

    public string Dequeue()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            string item = data[rand.Next(0, data.Count)];
            if (!data.Contains(item))
            {
                return item;
            }

            return data[rand.Next(0, data.Count)];
        }
    }

    public void Enqueue(string item)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            data.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public bool IsCount()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            return data.Count > 0;
        }
    }

    public void Load(string path)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (data.Count > 0)
            {
                data.Clear();
            }

            string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(path);

            for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content[i]))
                {
                    data.Add(content[i]);
                }
            }

            content = null;
        }
    }

    private Timer _timer;

    public void BlackTimer(string item, int interval)
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = interval;
        _timer.Elapsed += (x, y) => { _timer_Elapsed(_timer, item); };
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(Timer _timer, string blackProxy)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (!black.Contains(blackProxy))
            {
                data.Add(blackProxy);
                black.Remove(blackProxy);

                _timer.Stop();
                _timer.Dispose();
            }

            black.Add(blackProxy);
        }
    }
```

Или все таки это детский сад и такое реализуется вообще не так?

Comment: что такое data? что такое black? и зачем тут таймер вообще?

Comment: `Я написал такой код` так вы не пояснили почему написали именно такой код и что этот код делает.

Comment: `lock (lockObject)` это к чему тут вообще?

Comment: @tym32167 data это общая коллекция (List<string>) которая содержит весь список прокси, black это тоже коллекция, но для черного списка, каждый раз когда надо вытянуть одно значение из data я сверяю, есть этот элемент в черном списке.

Comment: @tym32167 блокировка нудна, потому что программа работает в многопотоке. 
Описание кода я вроде предоставил в самом вопросе

Comment: Покажите это в коде. Сейчас я смотрю на ваш код и просто не вижу в нем смысла. Я бы решил задачу кардинально по другому, но я не знаю всех ваших деталей,  потому и спращиваю почему код написал именно так, а не иначе.

Comment: Вашу задачу можно очень, очень сильно упростить. Делаете объект `{ Proxy, BlockDate }`, заполняете коллекцию ими и все, при каждом случае, когда нужна новая прокси, вы берете те, у которых `BlockDate` в пределах определенного значения, а когда прокся заблочилась, просто меняете ей дату и берете новую, вот, собственно, и все, без таймеров и других каких-либо коллекций.

Comment: @tym32167 привел полный код класса

Comment: Как минимум, ваш BlackTimer перетирает предыдущий таймер, то есть некоторые прокси будут заблокированы навсегда

Comment: плюс да, таймер тут не нужен по идее, нужно хранить дату и время разблокировки прокси.

Comment: @tym32167 понял, спасибо. Таймер, это то что первое мне пришло в голову

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Или все таки это детский сад и такое реализуется вообще не так?

Это детский сад и такое реализуется вообще не так :)

Первое, что могу предолжить, это не вникая в подробности, асинхронный метод. [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

```cs
public async void BanProxy(int timeout, string blackProxy)
{
    lock (lockObject)
        if (!data.Remove(blackProxy))
            return;
    await Task.Delay(timeout);
    lock (lockObject)
        if (!data.Contains(blackProxy))
            data.Add(blackProxy);
}
```

Сразу можете заметить, что вам больше не нужен блэклист.

Второе - использовать [потокобезопасные коллекции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1261366/373567) вместо локов.