# На сколько безопасно в данном случае использовать List?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

```
class ThreadSafePair<T1, T2> {

    object item1Lock = new object(), item2Lock = new object();

    T1 item1;
    T2 item2;

    public T1 Item1 {
        get { lock (item1Lock) return item1; }
        set { lock (item1Lock) item1 = value; }
    }

    public T2 Item2 {
        get { lock (item2Lock) return item2; }
        set { lock (item2Lock) item2 = value; }
    }

    public ThreadSafePair(T1 item1, T2 item2) {
        this.item1 = item1;
        this.item2 = item2;
    }
}

ConcurrentDictionary<long, ThreadSafePair<List<Update>, AutoResetEvent>> Collection =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<long, ThreadSafePair<List<Update>, AutoResetEvent>>();
```

Добавляет элементы в `Collection` и в `List<Update>` 1 поток. С каждым ключом соответственно здесь работает по 1 потоку - они читают и в дальнейшем очищают свой `List<Update>`, в каком то случае могут даже вовсе удалить элемент из `ConcurrentDictionary`. Возможно нужно заменить `List` на `ConcurrentBag`? Есть тут необходимость во `ThreadSafePair`?

Comment: В вашем коде никто ничего никуда не добавляет, а сами локи бессмысленные, так как возврат или установка значения ссылочного типа операция не требующая потокобезопасности .

Comment: Мало того, даже если бы то, что под локами у вас имело смысл, ваш класс все равно не является потокобезопасным, ведь если передать один и тот же объект дважды в него, вместо двух объектов, то ваши локи вас не спасут.

Comment: "_В вашем коде никто ничего никуда не добавляет_" - Я представил лишь структуру коллекции. Код, который с ней работает, слишком большой и нет смысла его выкладывать. _"ваш класс все равно не является потокобезопасным"_ - Вопрос не про класс больше, а про коллекцию. Убрать lock'и и заменить `List` на `ConcurrentBag`? Или как поступить?

Comment: ваш вопрос в принципе некорректен. Вот посмотрите на ваши геттеры/сеттеры - вот вы можете пояснить, зачем там вообще нужен lock? Потокобазопасность для списков важна для операций со списками, например добавить или удалить элемент. Операция "Вернуть указатель из геттера" вообще не нуждается в какой либо синхронизации.

Comment: Если с одним отдельным списком, то есть с ключом словаря работает только один поток, то можно использовать списки без каких-либо блокировок. А вообще у меня на эту тему есть вот такой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1261366/373567

Comment: "_Если с одним отдельным списком, то есть с ключом словаря работает только один поток, то можно использовать списки без каких-либо блокировок_" - Работает 2 потока. 1 поток читает и после этого очищает `List`, а так же может удалить элемент из `Collection`, другой поток только добавляет элементы в `Collection` И `List`.

Comment: @aepot Ваш ответ по ссылке слишком общий на мой взгляд. Добавлю пояснений на счёт `List`: после того как первый поток заполнит `List`, он даёт сигнал второму потоку и тот читает и очищает `List`. Наверное `List` можно оставить и не менять на "потокобезопасный" вариант. На счёт `ThreadSafePair` - он как понимаю тут вообще бессмысленный, нужна просто структура с 2 полями.

Comment: Только вот в теории в процессе чтения одним потоком, другой может добавить элементы в `List`, и первый, не увидев изменений, очистит список.

Comment: @D.Stark у меня ощущение, что вы знаете ответ на вопрос :)