# Потокобезопасный GetEnumerator

Tags: c#, .net

Имеют ли Mutex и lock одинаковый эффект в пределах одного процесса?

Если я хочу создать потокобезопасную коллекцию с использованием внутри списка, будет ли такой вызов безопасен (за время пока элементы коллекции будет перечисляться в цикле, сама коллекция может много раз измениться):

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
    lock (SyncObj) return InnerList.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Может нужно сделать так:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
    lock (SyncObj) return new List<object>(InnerList).GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: В первом случае вы получите исключение при попытке изменить список во время перечисления. Что именно нужно? Делайте под локом снапшот типа `foreach(var item in list.ToArray())` например. Вот еще это почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1261366/373567. Потокобезопасного энумератора не существует в природе. Либо вы перечисляете снэпшот, либо вы это делаете под локом, либо получаете непредсказуемое поведение.

Comment: _"В первом случае вы получите исключение при попытке изменить список во время перечисления."_ - Почему так происходит? Я думал в таком случае будет лишь непредсказуемое поведение как результат. _"Что именно нужно?"_ - Получить моментальный снимок коллекции и иметь возможность его перечислить.

Comment: _"Вот еще это почитайте ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1261366/373567"_ - Я знаком с потокобезопасными коллекциями. Иногда требуется реализовать именно потокобезопасный `List`, который не представлен в пространстве имён `System.Collections.Concurrent` (я думаю по причине того, что лучшего решения, чем просто обернуть все операции со списком `lock`'ами нет). _"Потокобезопасного энумератора не существует в природе."_ - Об этом в курсе. _"Делайте под локом снапшот типа foreach(var item in list.ToArray()) например"_ - Чем это отличается от моего второго варианта и зачем тут foreach?

Comment: Хотелось бы получить ответ и на самый первый вопрос.

Comment: Непредсказуемое поведение - это что написано в интерфейсе [IEnumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=netframework-4.8), а значит, каждая реализация интерфейса вольна понимать это по своему, например энемератор, который используется списком, [отслеживает версию коллекции и падает с исключением](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1140).

Comment: Если вы пишете потокобезопасный враппер коллекции и ваш враппер - это единственное, что имеет ссылку на коллекцию (а энумраторы и прочие получают только копию коллекции) + все операции у вас синхронизированы, то должно работать норм.

Comment: `лучшего решения, чем просто обернуть все операции со списком lock'ами нет` спорное утрверждение. Все "зависит" от требований.

Comment: `Имеют ли Mutex и lock одинаковый эффект в пределах одного процесса` смотря что называть эффект. оба предоставляют доступ к ресурсу только одному потоку. Но Мьютекс - это штука на уровне ОС работает, а значит шарится и между процессами, а значит работает гораздо медленней обычного монитора Lock

Comment: _"смотря что называть эффект"_ - Способ применения и функциональность. _"Но Мьютекс - это штука на уровне ОС работает, а значит шарится и между процессами"_ - Я уточнил - в  пределах одного процесса. _"а значит работает гораздо медленней обычного монитора Lock"_ - То есть если не требуется межпроцессорная синхронизация всегда лучше использовать lock?

Comment: _"спорное утрверждение. Все "зависит" от требований."_ - Речь идёт о потокобезопасной обёртке над `List`. Можете показать пример, где это сделано эффективней без `lock`'ов?

Comment: @tym32167 _"Непредсказуемое поведение - это что написано в интерфейсе IEnumerator, а значит, каждая реализация интерфейса вольна понимать это по своему, например энемератор, который используется списком, отслеживает версию коллекции и падает с исключением."_ - Это вы к вопросу о том почему перечислитель выдаст исключение, если коллекция будет изменена другим потоком? Скажите, второй пример кода может являться решением?

Comment: Второй пример кода имеет смысл только если остальная часть враппера как надо написана. Потому как если вы только этот метод синзронизируете, то все еще можете получать ошибки (если другие методы работы со списком не синхронизированы)

Comment: `Это вы к вопросу о том..` да

Comment: _"Второй пример кода имеет смысл только если остальная часть враппера как надо написана."_ - Само собой разумеется. Вопрос здесь идёт лишь про `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: тогда с точки зрения потокобезопасности норм выглядит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Имеют ли Mutex и lock одинаковый эффект в пределах одного процесса?

Эффект да, скорость - нет. Самый быстрый из двух будет `lock`.

Еще быстрее будет Reader/Writer lock, например на базе `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, так как он позволит хотя-бы безопасно читать коллекцию в многопоточке нескольким потокам сразу ([пример реализации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1261366/373567)).

> Если я хочу создать потокобезопасную коллекцию с использованием внутри списка, будет ли такой вызов безопасен

Первый вариант безопасен не будет, так как само перечисление будет происходить за пределами лока, а значит ваш `SyncObj` будет свободен для взятия другим локом. Но я бы в качестве снапшота использовал массив, а не список, он более легковесный.

Второй вариант делает снапшот коллекции под локом и отдает энумератор с нее, отличный вариант в плане того, что он не лочит саму коллекцию во время перечисления.

Но есть еще вариант

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    lock (SyncObj)
    {
        foreach (T item in InnerList)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Плюс - копия коллекции не будет создана, коллекция не будет изменена во время перечисления. Минус - коллекция будет заблокирована на время перечисления.

Вам решать, что из этого лучше сработает.